# Import GLFW function to Ada

Tags: ada, glfw, gnat-gps

How to import GLFW function to Ada?

Using GNAT GPS as compiler and have the following folder structure:

- test.adb
- test.gpr
- bin
- obj
- libglfw3.a
- lib

  - libglfw3.a

**test.gpr**

```
project test is
    for Source_Dirs use ("");
    for Main use ("test.adb");
    for Object_Dir use "obj";
    for Library_Dir use "lib";
    for Exec_Dir use "bin";
end test;
```

**test.adb**

```
with Interfaces.C;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure test is
    pragma Linker_Options("-lglfw3");
    pragma Linker_Options("-lgdi32");
    pragma Linker_Options("-lopengl32");
    function Init return Interfaces.C.int;
    pragma Import(C,Init,"glfwInit");
    success : Interfaces.C.int;
begin
   success := Init;
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(success'Img);
end test;
```

Compiling with `gprbuild -P test.gpr` and outputs:

```
p:/gnat/2014/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.4/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3
```

So I was thinking when *gdi32*, *winmm*, *opengl32* is found is because they are already installed on my PC. I don't know if they are needed, but just to be on the safe side. The *glfw3* lib is not found so I don't know if I'm using the Linker_Option the right way or where to put the *libglfw3.a* file. Is there a good way to link to c libraries?

Comment: Part of the answer : gcc -c -fdump-ada-spec-slim glfw3.h . See http://wiki.ada-dk.org/c_bindings_example or (considering open_gl) http://flyx.org/2012/06/13/adabindings1/

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma Linker_Options("-lglfw3dll");
```

Is a bad method, It should be like below:

```
pragma Linker_Options("-lglfw3");
```

To tell the linker to use library file `libglfw3.a`

To check `libglfw3.a` is in the object path used by GNAT, type the command

> gnatls -v

Complete Ada binding to both GLFW2 and GLFW3 with GPR project files are available at OpenGLAda currently at Github.

Comment: Corrected what you said about the lib format. Also I found some more info  [specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use) but the same problem is still remaining.